# Knockout.js - Interpreting the data object on click events

Tags: knockout.js

I'm working with Knockout.js, trying to figure out how to resolve a property of a data object passed as part of its click handler. So far I can only find/see the text definitions of functions associated with the object.

For example, in using Chrome to investigate the data object passed by a click binding, I can only find:

```
> data.CityId.toString
function toString() { [native code] }

> data.CityId.toString()
"function b(){if(0<arguments.length){if(!b.equalityComparer||!b.equalityComparer(d,arguments[0]))b.H(),d=arguments[0],b.G();return this}r.T.Ha(b);return d}"
```

### The program:

The program lists out several cities, and on click of the element, I'd like to call a function to update the data - passing in a parameter from the view model instance.

Although I'm using the mapping plugin, the view model is effectively:

- CityId
- CityName

The HTML template calling the method:

```
   <div data-bind="click: function(data, event) { UpdateForCity(data, event); }">
      <span data-bind="text: CityName"></span>
    </div>
```

The function to be called:

```
function UpdateForCity(data, event) {
    alert('CityId: ' + data.CityId); // This is the part where I'd like to resolve the value
}
```

The function receives the value, but all attempts of finding a way to resolve the property have eluded be so far. How can I resolve the CityId property in the example above? (And have I mis-understood anything in the MVVM/knockout pattern?)

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like your `toString()` method returns an observable.

Comment: Most of the methods in that space return a similar result - how do I resolve the current value of the observable?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there's a utility method for just this:

```
var cityId = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(data.CityId);
```

It looks like it would also be possible to attach a function to each instance of the view model item, but that would require a deeper understanding of the configuration of the mapping plugin...

Answer (score -1):

Just providing a fiddle example created by Ryan Niemeyer that I am referring now to solve my few knockout issues . Here is the link to the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/vdcUA/

If you need more information you can go and check out knockmeout site as well

Hope this helps